# I get an error in the while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I have some code that doesn't work, I placed an arrow at the error.

I'm suppose to make a  ~loop while (j > 0) AND (array at j-1 > Min)`.

What am I doing wrong? Why do I keep getting errors?

Please help! And thank you for reading! It might just be a simple stupid mistake. It tells me one is a int, other is boolean, what do I do?

```
private static int[] dorp(int[] myArray){
    int n = myArray.length;
    int swap;
     for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
        int j = i;
        int min = myArray[i];
      -->  while ((j = 0) && (myArray[j-1] > min)) {
        myArray[j]=myArray[j-1];
        j=j-1;
            }
        j=min;
        }
    return myArray;
}
```

New code

```
    int myArray[] = {1, 6, -1, 7, 83, 19, -3, 6, 2, 4, 6, 32, 66, -9};
    int n = myArray.length;
    myArray = doop(myArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}

private static int[] doop(int[] myArray) {
    int n = myArray.length;
    int swap;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int j = i;
        int min = myArray[i];
        while ((j == 0) && (myArray[j - 1] <= min)) {
            myArray[j] = myArray[j - 1];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        myArray[j] = min;
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(j = 0)
```

results into `int` and int `&&` `boolean` doesn't result into `boolean`, you want it `j==0` if your intention is to add comparison with 0

Comment: Thanks man, I did that, and i highly appreciate, i'll keep that knowledge in the back of my head for later, but now i'm getting errors. Exception main thread. Can you tell me whats wrong? Its suppose to sort all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

your while always false. j=0 means assign the 0 value to j. you need to change it like that

```
 while ((j == 0) && (myArray[j-1] > min)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to return the array since the array is passed by reference so any changes to elements inside myArray will be seen outside the function

your new doop function will be

```
private static void doop(myArray) {
    int temp,  i, j;                
    for (i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++){
        temp = myArray[ i ];
        //for(j = i - 1; (j >= 0) && (myArray[ j ] < temp); j--) // sort array in descending order
        for(j = i - 1; (j >= 0) && (myArray[ j ] > temp); j--) // sort array in ascending order  
        {
          myArray[ j+1 ] = myArray[ j ];
        }
        myArray[ j+1 ] = temp;    
  }

}
```